# Using BreezeJs and Mobx in react or vue

Tags: breeze, mobx

I guess if someone needs to migrate from a legacy breeze.js application to a newer framework except Angular like ReactJs or VueJs, then Mobx can be a great help to brings the observable objects to the project.

I was wondering is someone has gave it a go to provide some feedback and perhaps sharing some code.

Comment: You can use breeze-client@next with Vue.js.  See the [NorthwindVue demo app](https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-core-ng-demo/tree/master/NorthwindCore/NorthwindVue) for example.
IMHO breeze is still the best when you have relational data.

Comment: You can use breeze-client@next with React.  See the [northwind-react demo app](https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-core-ng-demo/tree/master/NorthwindCore/northwind-react) for example.  No Mobx required.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need MobX with Breeze because Breeze already provides this capability.  See the following example: [Creating a Breeze React App](https://github.com/Breeze/northwind-demo/blob/master/client/STEPS-Client-React.md)